# How to solve integral over $z^2 e^{-z^2/2}$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, gaussian-integral

I want to solve the following integral
$$\int_0^{\infty} x^2 \cdot N(x;\mu_x, \sigma^2_x) dx$$.

**How far I've come with my knowledge**

First I standardized the distribution with $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$. This gives me:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\mu/\sigma}^{\infty}(\sigma z+\mu)^2e^{-z^2/2}dz$$.

Then i multiplied out the equation and split it into three integrals.

$$\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\mu/\sigma}^{\infty}z^2 e^{-z^2/2}dz+ \frac{2\sigma\mu}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\mu/\sigma}^{\infty}z e^{-z^2/2}dz + \mu^2\int_{-\mu/\sigma}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}dz$$.

Knowing that $\int xe^{-cx^2}dx = -\frac{1}{2c}e^{-cx^2}$, the second integral can be solved:

$$\frac{2\sigma\mu}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$.

The third integral can be solved by using the cummulative distribution and thus gives:
$$\mu^2 \cdot \Phi(\frac{\mu}{\sigma})$$.

First of all - are my calculations correct so far? If yes,
how to solve the first integral and simplify the total equation? Is there a antiderivative of the term in order to solve it directly?

Thanks!

**EDIT - Idea**

Including $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ into to first integral gives

$$\sigma^2\int_{-\mu/\sigma}^{\infty}z^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}dz$$. Then it can be exploited that $\Phi(x) - x\phi(x) +C$ is the indefinite integral of $\int x^2\phi(x)$. Inserting the upper and lower bound of the integral gives
$$\sigma^2\left(\left[1 - \infty\cdot\phi(\infty) - \left(\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) +\frac{\mu}{\sigma} \cdot \phi(\frac{-\mu}{\sigma})\right)\right]\right) = \sigma^2\left(\left[1 - 0 - \left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right) +\frac{\mu}{\sigma} \cdot \phi(\frac{-\mu}{\sigma})\right)\right]\right) = \sigma^2 \Phi(\mu/\sigma) - \sigma\mu \phi(-\mu/\sigma)$$

Comment: Your work looks good.  Have you tried integrating by parts on the first integral?

Comment: hey, thanks for the hint! I'm quite new to these calculations, I might need to read about integrating by parts first

Comment: It's my favorite integration technique, well worth knowing.  You can try it on basically any integral.

Comment: could you give me a starting point?

Comment: $ \lim_{z \to \infty} z\cdot e^{-z^2/2} = \lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{z}{e^{z^2/2}} = 0$

Comment: thanks, i updated my approach. Is it correct?

Comment: I don't see any mistakes.

Comment: Alright,  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Integration by Parts is essentially the reverse of the product rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(UV) = U \frac{dV}{dx} + V \frac{dU}{dx}$$ so
$$\int_a^b\frac{d}{dx}(UV) dx = \int_a^b U \frac{dV}{dx} dx + \int_a^b V \frac{dU}{dx} dx$$ or
$$UV|_a^b = \int_a^b U dV + \int_a^b V dU$$ giving finally the rule:
$$\int_a^b U dV = UV|_a^b - \int_a^b V dU$$

To use the rule, you take your integral and factor it into your $U$ piece and your $dV$ piece.  You choose them so that a) you know how to integrate the $dV$, b) you can differentiate the $U$, and you expect the product $VdU$ to be easier to integrate than $UdV$.  If you have a polynomial times something else, very often (not always) the polynomial is a good choice for $U$.  Looking at your integral, if you want to integrate $e^{-z^2/2}$ you will want to grab a factor of $z$ from the $U$ part to make a better choice.  So $U = z$ and $dV = ze^{-z^2/2}$ would be a good starting point.

Comment: but doesn't that give $\int_a^b 1 \cdot -e^{-z^2/2}$? for that there is no antiderivative that can be written elementary

Comment: Right, but you are already dealing with that in the third integral anyway.

Comment: i had another idea..i will update my question

Comment: would you mind having another look at the updated approach?

Comment: I don't really follow what you are doing or where you got that indefinite integral from. I tried to check it by taking the derivative and I got $-x\phi'(x)$ Is that an integration by parts you used there, or something else?

Comment: I used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions. Under the chapter Indefinite integrals, the third entry shows $\int x^{2}\phi (x)\,dx=\Phi (x)-x\phi (x)+C$ . My approach was to transform the integral in order to obtain the standard normal distribution